# Work with 128bit or 256bit unsigned integers in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I'm setting up software to work with multiplication of large numbers, and I'd like to compare the speed between several techniques, one of which is OpenCL.  How can I pass in and multiply two 256-bit unsigned integers?  What are the performance implications of this?  What's the practical limit of how large numbers can get before the performance becomes terrible?

Comment: @Nesktarios were you able to figure out a workaround? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCL only has intrinsic support for 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers. There might be vendor extensions for big integers on some platforms, but at least on the ones I am familiar with, there is not. If you want larger integer types, you will have to implement them yourself.

Comment: Which, for 128bit integers, will cost you 4 64-bit multiplies and some shifts.

Comment: @Jasper Bekkers: I think you're not exact, because with 64-bit multiplies you can loose precision. Nektarious will have to use mul_hi function as well to get the carry, resulting in 7 multiplies.

Comment: In fact, this number can by probably lowered by [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), but the need of mul_hi stands.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The 4 64-bit multiplies will result in a value that fits in a 128-bit value and that effectively means you can only multiply 64-bit values.